# Form Field: How do I change the background on blur?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, styles

I managed to remove the background when the user clicks on the field but I cannot restore it when it blurs!

This is the field:

```
       <textarea class="question-box" style="width: 240px; background: 
    white url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png') no-repeat 
    50% 50%; color: grey;" cols="12" rows="5"  id="question-box-' . 
    $questionformid . '" name="title" onblur="if(this.value == '') { 
    this.style.color='#848484'; this.style.background='
white url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png') no-repeat 50% 50%';}" 
    onfocus="if (this.value == '') {this.style.color='#444'; 
    this.style.background='none';}" type="text" maxlength="200" size="28"></textarea>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you primarily need to support IE6/7, stop messing around with JavaScript for something that can be solved with CSS:

```
textarea.question-box {
    width: 240px; 
    background: white url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png') no-repeat 50% 50%; 
    color: grey;
}
textarea.question-box:focus {
    color: #444; 
    background: none;
}
```

If you do need to support IE6/7, or IE in compat or quirks mode, try [one of the bolt on solutions](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) already available.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onblur="if(this.value == '') { 
        this.style.color='#848484'; this.value=''this.style.background='
    white url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

You have "E" character after this line, that must be causing your problem.

Anyways, for switching background on elements use onfocus and onblur events

```
onfocus="var a = 'url(\'http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/form-focused.png\') repeat scroll 0 0 white'; this.style.background=a; return false;"

onblur="var a = 'url(\'http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/form-normal.png\') repeat scroll 0 0 white'; this.style.background=a; return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the character however it still doesn't work. I tried your onblur too and didn't work. Anyhow my onfocus is working, it's just the onblur that doesn't. It should put the background back on. mmm any other idea?? Thanks anyway

Comment: really strange, but i'd suggest that you use class switching, for example if you have jquery you can easly onfocus="$(this).addClass('focusedinput');" onblur="$(this).removeClass('focusedinput');" its much more effective than doing inline style.

Comment: I think I might try that. Can I do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is from the part this.value=''this.style.background='. You need a semi-colon there. And do you really want to set the value back to blank when the user clicks on it?

Comment: Yes, the image is just to draw attention. Where do I need to add a semi-colon??

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems that you didnt quite understood. jQuery is javascript lib used for easier javascript programming.

Add this into to your `<head></head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and than you can use

```
onfocus="$(this).addClass('focusedinput');" onblur="$(this).removeClass('focusedinput');"
```

as I mentioned in comment. That should toggle the class focusedinput who should hold the properties such as background or color of an element.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the quotes from the URL and it work.

Didn't work:

```
 this.style.background='white url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png') no-repeat 50% 50%'
```

Wodked:

```
 this.style.background='white url(http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/contawidget.png) no-repeat 50% 50%'
```

Comment: You really better change the `className` instead, will save you this whole quote-ache.